# How To store Value form QDateEdit in String?

Tags: qt, qdate

I want to store value from QDateEdit to String. I'have used following code:

`QString str = ui->dateeditobject->date().toString("dd/mm/yyyy")`

But the problem is, that the month value is not being stored as you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpokO.jpg).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Month is MM (uppercase), otherwise it is minutes

```
ui->dateeditobject->date().toString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString).